46/30 Crankset with Boost chainline (51,8)
I'm looking to ride a 148mm rear hub, i.e an ideal chainline of ~51,8mm but with 46/30 as I'm gonna usually ride Allroad (and Offroad only when it's not too muddy... 30 upfront und 42 in the back is more than enough for long ascents for me).
I've been looking into cranksets but I've only ever found cranks with a 51,8mm chainline running 36/22 (i.e FC-MT210-B) or thereabout, or cranks with a 48,8mm chainline running 46/30 (i.e Shimano Cues FC-U6000-2).
I've already went through Shimano Database (https://productinfo.shimano.com/en#/) and haven't found anything but I'm hoping for the aftermarket.
I'm flexible w.r.t what system the crank uses,though I prefer Hollowtech II. The frame has a 73mm BSA bottom bracket.
Any recommendations?

With the long chainstays of a mountain bike, would reducing the chainline to 49/50mm matter? In your lowest gear (1-1), the chain could foul the tyre if using the widest tyres the frame is designed for....but you could use a slightly narrower tyre.

There are two likely ways to make this happen:

Square taper with a much longer spindle than nominally intended.
A direct mount spider that can take 46-30 on a crank that has the DM interface it needs but was probably nominally intended for 1x or mountain 2x.

All of the FDs that will do a good job on 46/30 will likely need to be hacked to get to the chainline needed for the 46 in a Boost application.

The Microshift Advent FD works with a 48,8 or 51,8mm chainline and a 44-48 chainring. (Don't know whether they count as 'doing a good job' for you though, don't have any experience with Microshift FD yet.)
